# Parse subclass for ParseUser Return type

Tags: parse-platform, listener, subclass, return-type

Im subclassing parseUser , so when i look for user i use :

```
query.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<MySubClass>() {

            @Override
            public void done(MySubClass user, ParseException e) {
```

but when i need to user 
getCurrentUser or logInInBackground i getting ParseUser instead of MySubClass .

i user this methods :

```
MySubClass.logInInBackground(userName, "", new LogInCallback() {

    @Override
    public void done(ParseUser u, ParseException arg1) {

    }
});
```

but i want the callback to return MySubClass object like in my query .

the same with this :

```
MySubClass.getCurrentUser()
```

Answer (score 6):

Same Problem here.

Actually you can solve this by correctly subclassing your ParseUser.

```
@ParseClassName("_User")
public class User extends ParseUser {}
```

Then register your class before initializing parse.

```
ParseObject.registerSubclass(User.class);
```

You can then cast to your own subclass without a casting error:

```
User user = (User)ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
```

Comment: you cannot cast ParseUser to User like this

Answer (score 1):

As per this [article](https://www.parse.com/questions/unable-to-subclass-parseuser-in-android). You actually specifically need to refer to the _User "ParseClassName" when subclassing this object. It's super hairy, I was stuck on this for ages because for other classes you only need to refer to their name as seen in the Parse Data Browser, which in this case is "User", "Info", "Post" etc, but the User class requires the underscore.

Comment: article link broken :(